# Transform a Javascript Object to Function manually

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript.
I've read that an object which has an internal member `[[Call]]` produces `function` as the result of `typeof` that object.
I wonder whether I can set this internal member in my Javascript code, i.e. is something like this possible? :

```
function my_foo(){}

var my_obj = {};  // is the ';' an empty statement?

my_obj["[[Call]]"]=my_foo; // in my test, this didn't work
```

And if it is possible, would this change the result of typeof that object from `object` to `function`?

Comment: Why are you not just using `var my_obj = new my_foo();` if you want it of type `my_foo` extending on `function`?

Comment: @MartinBarker: Probably because `[[Call]]` [is defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#table-6) as an *internal method* (e.g., a reference to executable code). (It threw me at first too.)

Comment: @MartinBaker: As far as I can see (I'm learning), with `var my_obj = new my_foo();` I cannot do an invocation of the form `my_obj();` 

Suppose I have a function `A(f){...}`, that invokes the argument f, i.e. a call `f();`

I can do: `function B(){....} B['x']=10; .... A(B);` 

But what, if I have an existing object O with existing properties that I got passed as a parameter into a function of mine. I hoped I could associate the object with a new function body to pass it as an argument to the function A, i.e. that I could call 'A(O)' without an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've read that an object which has an internal member [[Call]] produces function as the result of typeof that object. I wonder whether I can set this internal member in my Javascript code, i.e. is something like this possible?

No. You cannot directly set or modify [internal slots](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) of JavaScript objects. That's part of why they're internal slots, not properties. Your code just creates a *property* called `[[Call]]`, which is unrelated to the internal slot. From the linked spec section:

> Internal slots correspond to internal state that is associated with objects and used by various ECMAScript specification algorithms. Internal slots are not object properties and they are not inherited. Depending upon the specific internal slot specification, such state may consist of values of any ECMAScript language type or of specific ECMAScript specification type values. Unless explicitly specified otherwise, internal slots are allocated as part of the process of creating an object and may not be dynamically added to an object. Unless specified otherwise, the initial value of an internal slot is the value `undefined`. Various algorithms within this specification create objects that have internal slots. However, the ECMAScript language provides no direct way to associate internal slots with an object.

There's no mechanism defined to let you set `[[Call]]`. (This isn't universally true of all internal slots; for instance, there's a mechanism that lets you set the `[[Prototype]]` internal slot of an object: [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object.setprototypeof). But there isn't one for `[[Call]]`.)

Comment: At rare times i wish i could up vote twice and this is one of them. You provided a good answer then edited to provide an awesome answer. but add your citations for your quotes would you :)

Comment: @MartinBarker: Very kind. :-) I'm kind of glad you can't, though; +7 seems plenty upvoted already...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!